# how to avoid shrinkage of plots in spyder?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am having data of 100 rows as:

```
Name    Working   Sleep
Jordan   12        12
John     18         6
George   10         8
David     8         8
```

So to visualize the `Working` v/s `Sleep` for each person:

```
 df[["Working", "Sleep"]].T.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(9, 5), label = ["Name"])
```

but I get the plots too shrinked, how to avoid this ? I am working on spyder idle with python 2.7.

[image: Shrinked pie charts]

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the `figsize` attribute in order to find the correct visualization.
Something like `figsize=(14, 3)` should solve the problem.